# OIDC & AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, openid-connect

I can't seem to get any AngularJS library with OIDC working with Internet Explorer 11. The redirect (cross-domain) works but when it returns it doesn't enable the storage of the token and it says the user is unauthorized. There are no errors in the console or anything very frustrated.

All the libraries work fine in Chrome & Firefox.

The ones I have used are:

Manfred Stayer's OIDC client
Thinktecture's OIDC.js client

Comment: I believe this has something to do with CORS when I used the same domain name it worked fine on IE as well.